# Groovy SimpleTemplateEngine and XML array variables

Tags: xml, templates, groovy

We have an app using Groovy SimpleTemplateEngine to generate text documents. The input is a parsed XML document, and we can generally reference any of these fields from expressions in the template:

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(xmldocument)
def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
def script = new File(template_file).text
def vars = [xml: xml, ... ]
output = engine.createTemplate(script).make(vars).toString()
```

In the template script, we reference elements from the XML document using a Groovy expression syntax like this: `Hello ${xml.FirstName}` (assuming "FirstName" is part of the XML parsed above).

The problem we're having is understanding the syntax to use when referencing items in an XML array. For example, we have XML like this:

```
<Contact>
  <Name>111</Name>
  <Phone>111</Phone>
</Contact>
<Contact>
  <Name>222</Name>
  <Phone>222</Phone>
</Contact>
```

What would be the syntax of the expression in the template file that would let us reference (say) the Name and Phone of the second contact? We've tried variations on `${xml.Contact[1].Name}` but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the xml (corrected to have `</Phone>` close tags:

```
def xmldocument = '''<Contacts>
                    |    <Contact>
                    |        <Name>111</Name>
                    |        <Phone>111</Phone>
                    |    </Contact>
                    |    <Contact>
                    |        <Name>222</Name>
                    |        <Phone>222</Phone>
                    |    </Contact>
                    |</Contacts>'''.stripMargin()    

def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(xmldocument)
```

And the template:

```
def script = 'Hello ${xml.Contact[1].Name.text()}'
```

Then you can do:

```
import groovy.text.*

def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
def vars = [xml: xml]
output = engine.createTemplate(script).make(vars).toString()
```

And

```
assert output == 'Hello 222'
```

Will pass

Comment: Apologies for the sloppy XML, and thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Your sample works - which is a good thing, since yours is the syntax we were expecting to work all along. Still, we are unfortunately getting an exception (No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [1]) on the call to createTemplate() when we run against live data. More debugging to do...

Comment: Okay, we found the issue...another field in the template file we use referenced an XML variable that happened to have an embedded hyphen. Since these files are generated automatically, it wasn't that obvious to us until we got a deeper look, and then we saw an expression like this: ${xml.user-name.FirstName.text()}. Wrapping the variable name in single quotes - ${xml.'user-name'.FirstName.text() - seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Ahhhh yeah... Glad you found it! :-)